# Add 'at least one letter, upper or lower case at any position' to existing regex (javascript)

Tags: javascript, regex

I already have the following regex: `^([^\s]+\s)*([^\s]+$)`

It does the following:

- No spaces at start
- No spaces at end
- No double spaces in the middle
- Any character

But now I need for it to include at least one letter upper or lower case at any position.

I tried playing arround with [A-Za-z] at several places but was unsuccesful.

How can I acomplish this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Single spaces are allowed mid-string?

Comment: Pretty sure `\S` is the same as `[^\s]` (may be more readable)

Comment: almost every regex engine treats escaped lowercase codes as "the thing" and uppercase as "not the thing", so you can make your regex much more readable by swapping those `[^\s]` for just `\S`, turning it into the more readable `^(\S+\s)*(\S+)$` The real question, though, is why you need to do this. Are you just trying to figure out regular expressions, or do you actually need to solve a problem? (in which case this feels like probably a misapplication of regex)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should do it:

```
^(\S\s?)*[A-Za-z](\s?\S)*$
```

1. This doesn't accept the empty string
2. It only accepts strings of length 1 if they look like `[A-Za-z]`
3. We disallow whitespace at the beginning by requiring that any whitespace character be preceded by a non-whitespace character to the left of the `A-Za-z`
4. And we disallow whitespace at the end of the string by requiring that any whitespace character be followed by a non-whitespace character to the right of the `A-Za-z`
5. Double spaces are covered by 3 and 4 since any space must appear adjacent to a non-space everywhere in the string

Comment: this did it exactly, thanks Purag, and thanks to everybody for your answers

Answer (score 1):

Try this Regex:

```
^(?!\s)(?!.*\s$)(?!.*?(\s)\1)(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z]).+$
```

[**Click For Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/ZRTl39/3)

**Explanation:**

- `^` - asserts the start of the string
- `(?!\s)` - negative lookahead to validate that the next character is not a whitespace
- `(?!.*\s$)` - negative lookahead to make sure that the last character is not a whitespace
- `(?!.*?(\s)\1)` - negative lookahead to make sure that the test string doesn't have any consecutive spaces
- `(?=.*?[A-Z])` - positive lookahead to make sure that there is a capital letter somewhere in the string
- `(?=.*?[a-z])` - positive lookahead to make sure that there is a small letter somewhere in the string
- `.+` - Once all the above conditions are satisfied, match 1+ occurrences of any character(except a newline character)
- `$` - asserts the end of the string